# How to get PrimarySMTPaddress for list of LinkedMasterAccounts

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

In Exchange 2007 management shell I can get the PrimarySmtpAddress for a specific LinkedMasterAccount with this command:

`get-mailbox -Resultsize Unlimited | ? { $_.LinkedMasterAccount -eq 'mydomain\peter' }  | select Name, Primarysmtpaddress`

But if I have a list of LinkedMasterAccounts in a csv file, how can I get their PrimarySmtpAddress?

Comment: How you tried experimenting with the Import-CSV command?

Comment: Yes, I tried but no luck, Eg. `import-csv c:\userlist.txt | foreach -process { get-mailbox | ? { $_.LinkedMasterAccount -eq "UserAccount" } | select Name, Primarysmtpaddress }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import-csv c:\userlist.txt | foreach -process { $UserAccount = $_;get-mailbox | ? { $_.LinkedMasterAccount -eq $UserAccount } | select Name, Primarysmtpaddress }
```

Comment: What's the format of your input file? could you please show an example

Comment: Can you run Import-CSV C:\userlist.txt on it's own and see if it does return a result? I doubt it will because the example you've given is not CSV. In that case try using Get-Content instead of Import-Csv

Comment: It's a text file with 3 lines. `1stline:UserAccount 2ndline:mydomain\peter 3rdline:mydomain\mary`

Comment: in that case the import-csv command should work. Have you tried to run the import-csv command on it's own and see what is the output? try Import-Csv C:\userlist.txt

Comment: I just run `import-csv c:\userlist.txt` and the output is correct. It display the header "UserAccount" and the two users (all in one row as expected).

Comment: Try the whole command, but replace Import-Csv with Get-Content and that should work as I've just tested it.

Comment: I just noticed you said "all in one row", you'd have to have each username on a separate line in order for this to work.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I mean all the results in one column.

Comment: This is similar of what I want to do: [powershell.com/cs/forums/t/12625.aspx](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/t/12625.aspx)